# architecture for modular socket.io in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, socket.io, npm

in a  node.js app, let's say i have a *app.js* like this

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();

var server = http.createServer(app);

...

module.exports = {
  app:app,
  server:server
}
```

also, there is */lib/sockets.js*, where all the logic of socket.io should go in. It looks like this:

```
var server = require('../app.js').server;
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('event', function(msg) {
    socket.emit('news', msg});
  });
});

module.exports = io;
```

Is it good practice to require the `server` from *app.js* here? If not, what would be a better solution? thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try having your sockets.js file export a function. Then require the sockets file in your app.js and pass in any relevant arguments.

In your lib/sockets.js:

```
module.exports = function(server){

    var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('event', function(msg) {
            socket.emit('news', msg);
        });
    });

    return io;
};
```

And in your app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var io = require("./lib/sockets")(app);
```

Comment: this works. great, thx! now, what if i wanted to call 'emit' in a third module? can i export the io object in some way from here to use it in another module?

Comment: you would follow the same pattern with the third module. it would export a function that has the io object as a parameter. then in your sockets file you would require in this third module and pass the io object as an argument to the new required function.